# AppSettings in DB instead of App.Config

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Updated Question  for more clarity :
How to load app setting stored in DB which is environment specific(Have column for with values O,T,A,P) and for specific business application instance .
example : I am from company A, my current instace should only have all entiry/data reference for A and specific environment setting for A .

Application that I am creating have few application instance inside it .
Its like tool for payroll management but tool is desgined to handle multiple instance parralllely.
So many companies can configure there system and use it parrallely.

It included UI for setting and Soap for CRUD for various entities.
I hope context is clear you all.

Problem is : 
There can be alot of configurations details, which are similar in nature but different for business instance .

so I am planning to store setting in Database table "AppSettings" .
which will have foreign key from business instance so that when fetched it only gets setting for that specific instance.

My Concern and Actual question :
We have OTAP (Local, Testing, Acceptance, Production), all have different settings value.
so in every environment i have to query for specific environment for setting.

That doesnt sound optimum solution.
Any suggestions or betting solution will appreciated.

Comment: I assume you also have different database (instances ) for the different environments? Then this isn't a problem i think? You interchange the connectionstring for each different environment and it gets the right DB

Comment: nope.. One db instance as this tool is not very big on DB.. and we have app table which holds applications instace details.. and this app table is referenced every where..

Comment: @RTWorkSpace what is the question? Just write a proper query that loads the settings for the environment you want. The question is unclear and throwing multiple dots in the middle of the sentence makes it *harder* to understand what you are asking

Comment: @RTWorkSpace perhaps the real question isn't how to read settings for a specific environment but reorganizing the code so it can work with multiple environments? Perhaps make it so it *doesn't* care about the environment once the configuration settings are loaded?

Comment: @RTWorkSpace Why do you have OTAP but only one Database for all environments, i realy think you need to seperate those if you want to have a good OTAP experience.

Comment: I have updated the question : I hope it helps.. But system architechure was created by someone else...I am trying to make it more usable. 
Updated Question  for more clarity :
How to load app setting stored in DB which is environment specific(Have column for with values O,T,A,P) and for specific business application instance .
example : I am from company A, my current instace should only have all data from A and specific environment setting for A .

Comment: This is called multi tenanting. Is there _any_ crosstalk between data in this database? If not, just create different tenants in different databases

Comment: Thanks Nick.. That looks closest to my problem..  I will explore that

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I like your comment about the multi tenancy but i still think this is not the answer to the problem. It sounds like the OP has a `Multi Tenant` architecture already because of the businessinstance reference he is referring too

Comment: No it's not an answer. Rather it's a suggestion to not over complicate if it isn't necessary

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question:

```
select * from AppSettings where businessinstance = x and environemt = 'Test'
```

table definition:

- ID (int auto increment) // Optional
- Businessinstance (PK, FK int)
- Key (PK unique constraint, string)
- value (string)
- environment (PK string/int)

the businessInstance, key and environment should be unique constraint together.
so create the PK like that. And have an ID to easy update